# How to get index position of a string enum in Typescript, give the type value itself?

Tags: typescript, react-native

```
export enum Environment {
  Sandbox = "SANDBOX",
  Production = "PRODUCTION",
}
```

I also have

```
const [selectedEnvironment, setSelectedEnvironment] = useState<Environment>(Environment.Sandbox); // Note it is not string "SANDBOX".
```

I tried `Object.keys(Environment).indexOf(selectedEnvironment)`, but it returns -1. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any help is appreciated as I am new to TypeScript. I looked at several other questions/answers but it seems to need the key/value to match exactly. Thank you.

Comment: What is not working? https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-dijkstra-0n20fu?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A16%2C31

Comment: I set the initial value to Sandbox and `Object.keys(Environment).indexOf(selectedEnvironment)` is returning -1 for me.

Comment: My bad, i read your comment and i felt you are getting wrong value of Sandbox key, didnt read the index issue.
If that comment is incorrectly mentioned, please remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiBuBLATgexBUAXKBvAUFFAMoCGIAJgEaoAeUAvFAETECCAcgCIBCA8gA1mAGkJQACmgpgAxlkTpGLcQCU+XAKoBhACoBJPhxH4AvvhnoAzjgDWwAJ6WlfKgCtgcgHR3HACjhIaBjYAJQA3OZWqAA2wJ7RqADmvj6WIZEgljFxCckBKOiYIFieZJQ0tOkWmdnxSSkOlp6IlMC0fABm-ggFwcWl5NR0IelAA).

```
enum Environment {
  Sandbox = "SANDBOX",
  Production = "PRODUCTION",
}
const keys = Object.keys(Environment);
console.log(keys) // ["Sandbox", "Production"]
console.log(Environment.Sandbox) // SANDBOX
console.log(keys.indexOf(Environment.Sandbox)) -1
```

You would need `Object.values(Environment)`.

Comment: Thanks! What a stupid mistake I made!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) instead of `Object.keys`. Since "SANDBOX" is the value.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import reactLogo from "./assets/react.svg";
import "./App.css";

export enum Environment {
  Sandbox = "SANDBOX",
  Production = "PRODUCTION",
}

function App() {
  const [selectedEnvironment, setSelectedEnvironment] = useState<Environment>(
    Environment.Production
  );
  const val = Object.values(Environment).indexOf(selectedEnvironment);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{selectedEnvironment}</p>
      <p>{val}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cool-dijkstra-0n20fu?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A12%2C27)